# Thread Join appears to be deadlocking

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Could somebody shed some light on this error being reported:

```
"main" prio=5 tid=1 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40b97568 self=0x40b5ba68
  | sysTid=29071 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074202160
  | schedstat=( 2218977000 625819000 2260 ) utm=177 stm=44 core=0
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x412f4160> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=12 (Thread-699)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:364)
  at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:761)
  at com.pyesmeadow.pendulumclock.PendulumAppView.pause(PendulumAppView.java:419)
```

It seems to indicate that it's waiting on a thread with an id of 12. Looking at the stack traces, I have the following for thread #12:

```
"Thread-699" prio=5 tid=12 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41715d38 self=0x678ba008
  | sysTid=29098 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1642643840
  | schedstat=( 12528326000 501640000 3154 ) utm=1206 stm=46 core=0
  #00 pc 0000dc70 /system/lib/libc.so (__futex_syscall3+8)
  #01 pc 0001212c /system/lib/libc.so
  #02 pc 0001a9cf /system/lib/libgui.so
  #03 pc 00021351 /system/lib/libgui.so     (android::SurfaceTextureClient::disconnect(int)+32)
  #04 pc 000213c7 /system/lib/libgui.so     (android::SurfaceTextureClient::~SurfaceTextureClient()+22)
  #05 pc 00021445 /system/lib/libgui.so     (android::SurfaceTextureClient::~SurfaceTextureClient()+4)
  #06 pc 0000ee89 /system/lib/libutils.so (android::RefBase::decStrong(void const*) const+40)
  #07 pc 000497db /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::sp<android::InputChannel>::~sp()+10)
  #08 pc 000567e1 /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
  #09 pc 0001de30 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
  #10 pc 0004d083 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+394)
  #11 pc 00027260 /system/lib/libdvm.so
  #12 pc 0002bb68 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+180)
  #13 pc 0005f7f1 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+272)
  #14 pc 0005f81b /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
  #15 pc 000543d3 /system/lib/libdvm.so
  #16 pc 00012dd0 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+48)
  #17 pc 00012528 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+172)
  at android.view.Surface.isValid(Native Method)
  at com.pyesmeadow.pendulumclock.PendulumAppView$WorkerThread.run(PendulumAppView.java:169)
```

Basically, that thread is responsible for updating the UI. The line of code it is referring to is a call to `isValid()`:

```
if( _surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid() )
{
    // ...
}
```

Going back to the first stack dump (above), it seems that the problem is occurring in the call to `_workerThread.join()` (_workerThread is the thread with an id of #12) in this code:

```
public void pause()
{   
    _workerThread.setRunning( false );

    // Wait for the background thread to terminate.

    while( true )
    {
        try
        {
            _workerThread.join();
            break;
        }
        catch( InterruptedException ex )
        {
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that by calling `join()` on the worker thread a deadlock is occurring but I don't know why.

Any help would be appreciated.

Wayne.

******** *UPDATE* **************

Here is the code for my `run()` method inside the worker thread:

(note that in the production version of my code _running\ is a **non-volatile** boolean)

```
    public void setRunning( boolean flag )
    {
        _running = flag;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {   
        int previousIndex = 0;

        _timeSwingStarted = new Date();

        while( _running )
        {
            if( _swingPath == null || _swingPath.isEmpty() )
                continue;

            if( Thread.interrupted() )
                break;

            if( _mode == PendulumMode.Swinging )
            {
                Date current = new Date();
                long elapsed = current.getTime() - _timeSwingStarted.getTime();
                int index = (int) Math.floor( ((double) Math.min(elapsed, 2000.0f) / 2000.0f) * (_swingPath.size() - 1) );

                index = Math.max( Math.min( index, _swingPath.size() - 1), 0 );

                if( index == previousIndex )
                    continue;

                // Calculate the position of the pendulum and render it on the display

                _currentPosition = _swingPath.get( index );

                // only render the UI if there is a valid surface to render on

                if( _surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid() )
                    _theme.render( _currentPosition, _scrollOffsetY, _showFPS );

                // Check whether the direction of the pendulum has changed

                previousIndex = index;

                if( index >= _swingPath.size() - 1 )
                    _timeSwingStarted = new Date();
            }


            //
            // Check whether we should close the app automatically if a
            // specified battery level has been reached.
            //

            if( _closeWhenBatteryLow && isBatteryLevelBelowThreshold() )
            {
                //
                // Schedule a shutdown time and notify the user in case they wish
                // to change their minds by adjusting the app settings.
                //

                if( _shutDownTime == null )
                {
                    _shuttingDownReason = ShutdownReason.BatteryLow;
                    _shutDownTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                    _shutDownTime.add( Calendar.MINUTE, 2 );

                    ((Activity) _context).runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            showWarning( getResources().getString( R.string.batteryLowClosingMessage ) );
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            //
            // Determine whether it's time to shutdown the app, if so the perform
            // some extra checks to ensure that the user hasn't changed their minds
            // since the initial message was displayed.
            //

            if( _shutDownTime != null )
            {
                Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

                if( now.after( _shutDownTime ) )
                {
                    if( _shuttingDownReason == ShutdownReason.BatteryLow )
                    {
                        if( _closeWhenBatteryLow && isBatteryLevelBelowThreshold() )
                        {
                            ((Activity) _context).finish();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            _shuttingDownReason = ShutdownReason.None;
                            _shutDownTime = null;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            try
            {
                Thread.sleep( _sleepDuration );
            }
            catch( InterruptedException e )
            {
                /* at least we tried */
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does `setRunning(false)` do?

Comment: setRunning(false) simply sets the `running` flag to false. I check the  `running` flag on each iteration of the loop in the worker thread.

Comment: pause() is called in my main activity's `onPause()` event.

Answer (score 1):

This line seems to indicate a problem:

```
_workerThread.setRunning( false );
```

Are you polling a boolean flag somewhere to see if you need to stop? It should be declared `volatile` in that case.

Comment: Yes, I am checking that field within the worker thread. It wasn't volatile but after reading a thread elsewhere earlier I noticed that it should be volatile because I am setting it in another thread. Do you think that is the problem then?

I was led to believe that the problem originated from my call to surfaceHolder.IsValid() within the worker thread... maybe that's a red-herring (!?)

Comment: @wh1974: Try to set it to volatile. If it's not volatile the value may get cached in a CPU register and you are not guaranteed that the worker thread will read the updated value.

Comment: Ok, I will try that thank you. Like I said the code has worked fine since last year. Guess this is one of those 'hard to reproduce' areas which I'll just have to wait to see if it resolves the problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    while( true ){
        _workerThread.interrupt();
        try
        {
            _workerThread.join();
            break;
        }
        catch( InterruptedException ex )
        {
        }
     }
```

With mine thread it works fine like that..

**EDIT:**

Tudor has your solution in the comments of my post.

Comment: So is the call to `interrupt()` important?

The reason I ask is because my code (without the call to `interrupt()` has worked without any problems for the past 9 months.

Comment: hmm... you cloud be right... but: An interrupt is an indication to a thread that it should stop what it is doing and do something else. So i thought, that before you have to jaoin a thread you have to interrupt it
But to be sure:
can you show me your whole source code, also from "_workerThread"?

Comment: If the OP is using a loop in the Worker with a bool as "runFlag" and sets it to flase for finishing instead of checking isInterrupted(), it should work without the interrupt. But, as Tudor stated, it would have to be marked as volatile.

Comment: another question. is your method "setRunning" of the _workingThread syncronized?

Comment: I've updated my original post with the contents of the workerThreads `run()` method.

Comment: change the type of "public void setRunning( boolean flag )" to "public synchronized void setRunning( boolean flag )"

Comment: @Mr.S: That won't change anything. Assignments of booleans are atomic, and in the absence of volatile you'd still need a memory fence when the flag is polled. `volatile` should solve it.